# Alternative to -pg with Clang?

Tags: c, gcc, profiling, clang, gprof

I wish to profile CPU (sample if possible), with as small a performance impact as possible (hence similar to GCC's `-pg`), binaries compiled with Clang. Is there an alternative that uses instrumentation of the code, or produces output similar to gprof?

Comment: You'd probably better ask that on the clang's developers list, no?

Comment: You really want output similar to gprof?

Comment: Yeah why not? It's clear and comprehensive. I've never found a usable alternative, valgrind comes the closest.

Comment: These pages are full of people trying to make sense off gprof output. 1) It's *blind to blocked time*, like IO. 2) You need to train yourself to ignore "self time", it being nearly useless. 3) Similar for all the call counts and function timings. 4) No line-level info. 5) The call-graph is nice & formally interesting, and also nearly useless. I'll grant you it's usable, like a good reliable car, when you have to cross a river.

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey: I'm aware of 1, 2, and on 3 and 4 you are wrong. As for 5, why do you think I'm using C? gprof generates consist output, with minimal impact on performance. I've tried to find an alternative that deals with blocking time among other things without luck. gprof with its shortcomings is still superior.

Comment: For alternative tools, you might consider Zoom or LTProf. For the points above, consider points 6, 2, 3 of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343 which also points to the technique I've relied on for decades, and a thorough example where most tools today would be left in the dust, *especially* gprof and its kin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I received a [good answer](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2010-September/011255.html) on the [Clang mailing list](http://lists.llvm.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/cfe-dev). To summarize, the use of [Google Performance Tools](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools) was the best fit.

Comment: Is that still the last word 6 years on?

Comment: @kynan: Donno, I've moved on to Go.

Comment: gperftools has [moved to github](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools).

Comment: clang has a `-fprofile-instr-generate ` compiler+linker flag. It doesn't measure CPU but It gives line counters for each of the line in code executed. It can help you find code that is run the most and help optimize.
http://cmdlinelinux.blogspot.com/2018/04/profiling-c-code-with-clang-using.html

Comment: Clang seems to accept "-pg" but doesn't link saying "undefined reference to mcount"

Comment: @wingerse Try linking against gcrt0.o instead of crt0.o if you have it, or linking against libgmon.a/libgmon.so if you have it, or compiling gmon.c and linking against it.

Answer (score 4):

### https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-pg

now clang already support "-pg"

Comment: Define "support"! On Windows with llvm-mingw-20231003-msvcrt-x86_64 using -pg option (for both compile and link) generates linker error: `undefined symbol: mcount`. There are not many results on Google or Bing, but apparently many platforms are just not supported for -pg. (gcc version x86_64-13.2.0-posix-seh-msvcrt-rt_v11-rev0 works fine.)

Comment: @StevenSpark Be sure to link against libgmon.a (from gmon.c). Note that, at the time of writing, that file is licensed under the BSD 3-clause license.

Comment: Also, you probably want to use `-pg -mfentry`, which doesn't use `mcount`. Here's some discussion: https://lwn.net/Articles/441729/