# Is it possible to know the address of a cache miss?

Tags: caching, x86-64, processor

Whenever a cache miss occurs, is it possible to know the address of that missed cache line? Are there any hardware performance counters in modern processors that can provide such information?

Comment: MetallicPriest, you can start from simulating the cache hierarchy with vallgrind's tool cachegrind - http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html

Comment: And there was project to profile data addresses from Pentium4 PEBS - http://www.lifl.fr/west/courses/cshp/doc/profguide/node10.html  = http://sourceforge.jp/projects/hardmeter + ADAPTOR

Comment: You can of course get the address *of the instruction* that caused the cache miss, using perf counters.  So on Linux you can `perf record -e L1-dcache-loads ./a.out` and then `perf report -Mintel`.  Often you know what array an instruction is accessing, so in many cases this is enough.  (There are counters for other levels of cache, too.  Get `ocperf.py` and use `ocperf.py list` for the full set of supported HW counters).

Comment: @PeterCordes - the PMU also provides the data address on recent implementations as part of it's "memory PEBS" events. It also tells you if the access was an L1 hit, LFB hit, whether it was locked, what the TLB behavior was, and lots of other goodies! This is exposed on Linux as part of `perf mem`.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, on modern Intel hardware there are *precise memory sampling events* that track not only the address of the instruction, but the data address as well. These events also includes a great deal of other information, such as what level of the cache hierarchy the memory access was satisfied it, the total latency and so on.

You can use `perf mem` to sample this information and produces a report.

For example, the following program:

```
#include <stddef.h>

#define SIZE (100 * 1024 * 1024)

int p[SIZE] = {1};

void do_writes(volatile int *p) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i += 5) {
        p[i] = 42;
    }
}

void do_reads(volatile int *p) {
    volatile int sink;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i += 5) {
        sink = p[i];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    do_writes(p);
    do_reads(p);
}
```

compiled with:

```
g++  -g -O1 -march=native   perf-mem-test.cpp   -o perf-mem-test
```

and run with:

```
sudo perf mem record -U ./perf-mem-test && sudo perf mem report
```

Produces a report of memory accesses sorted by latency like this:

[image: perf-mem report output]

The `Data Symbol` column shows where address the load was targeting - most here show up as something like `p+0xa0658b4` which means at an offset of `0xa0658b4` from the start of `p` which makes sense as the code is reading and writing `p`. The list is sorted by "local weight" which is the access latency in reference cycles<sup>1</sup>.

Note that the information recorded is only a *sample* of memory accesses: recording every miss would usually be way too much information. Furthermore, it only records loads with a latency of 30 cycles or more by default, but you can apparently tweak this with command line arguments.

If you're only interested in accesses that miss in all levels of cache, you're looking for the "Local RAM hit" lines<sup>2</sup>. Perhaps you can restrict your sampling to only cache misses - I'm pretty sure the Intel memory sampling stuff supports that, and I think you can tell `perf mem` to look at only misses.

Finally, note that here I'm using the `-U` argument after `record` which instructs `perf mem` to only record userspace events. By default it will include kernel events, which may or may not be useful for your. For the example program, there are many kernel events associated with copying the `p` array from the binary into writable process memory.

Keep in mind that I specifically arranged my program such that the global array `p` ended up in the initialized `.data` section (the binary is ~400 MB!), so that it shows up with the right symbol in the listing. The vast majority of the time your process is going to be accessing dynamically allocated or stack memory, which will just give you a raw address. Whether you can map this back to a meaningful object depends on if you track enough information to make that possible.

---

<sup>1</sup> I *think* it's in reference cycles, but I could be wrong and the kernel may have already converted it to nanoseconds?

<sup>2</sup> The "Local" and "hit" part here refer to the fact that we hit the RAM attached to the current core, i.e., we didn't have go to the RAM associated with another socket in a multi-socket NUMA configuration.

Comment: you should mention that PEBS = precise event-based sampling.  I didn't find a good URL about PEBS itself, just pages that mention it as something used by a specific profiler.

Comment: Oddly enough, I was just looking for a good link specific to PEBS memory profiling, but I didn't find one. The SDM covers it in detail of course.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I gave up trying to find a good link and just removed PEBS.

Comment: You missed a 2nd occurrence.  Just write "PEBS (precise event-based sampling)" the first time you use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the exact virtual or physical address of **every** cache miss on a particular processor, that would be very hard and sometimes impossible. But you are more likely to be interested in expensive memory access patterns; those patterns that incur large latencies because they miss in one or more levels of the cache subsystem. Note that it is important to keep in mind that a cache miss on one processor might be a cache hit on another depending on design details of each processor and depending also on the operating system.

There are several ways to find such patterns, two are commonly used. One is to use a simulator such as [gem5](http://www.gem5.org/Main_Page) or [Sniper](http://snipersim.org/w/The_Sniper_Multi-Core_Simulator). Another is to use hardware performance events. Events that represent cache misses are available but they do not provide any details on why or where a miss occurred. However, using a profiler, you can approximately associate cache misses as reported by the corresponding hardware performance events with the instructions that caused them which in turn can be mapped back to locations in the source code using debug information. Examples of such profilers include [Intel VTune Amplifier](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe/) and [AMD CodeXL](http://gpuopen.com/compute-product/codexl/). The results produced by simulators and profilers may not be accurate and so you have to be careful when interpreting them.