# Finding the cpu intensive parts of an application

Tags: qt, performance-testing

I have developed a quite big QT application, and although it is good in terms of performance, it is not as I expected it to be. I am looking for a tool to help me find the parts that are using cpu/gpu more than others. The operating system is not limited, as I can use Linux/Mac/Windows, and all are quite similar, although Linux is faster than the other two. Any hints and ideas would be appreciated. The code size is about 18000 lines of code now, and it is written in c++. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The tool you are looking for is called a profiler, what toolchain are you using?

Comment: Maybe you can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554/whats-the-best-free-c-profiler-for-windows).

Comment: thanks man. QtSDK, qt creator, gcc on linux, mingw on windows, and clang on macosx.

Comment: and also thanks for the term profiler!

Comment: [gprof](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_80.html) is the profiler for gcc.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769057/alternative-to-pg-with-clang for a pointer about profiling with clang.

Comment: There's some info on the Qt wiki: https://wiki.qt.io/Profiling-and-Memory-Checking-Tools